# Помогите, пожалуйста, найти корень в слове "просека". Укажите проверочное слово буквы Е в данном слове

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

Какой корень в слове "просека"? Какое слово является проверочным для буквы Е?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про — приставка, сек — корень, а — окончание, просек — основа слова. Проверить букву Е можно однокоренным "пересечь".